# How to Scale in and out based on SQS message level

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, autoscaling

How to scale in and out ec2 instances?

I have ASG with min = 2 max = 2 and desired = 2

I want add more instances when SQS message count reaches certain number say 500.

I have implemented the scaling out part by creating an alarm on 'ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible' which adds more instances (maximum of 2) - Good

But this required that I create another alarm to scale in when message count reaches below 50. - not ideal

Fine i created it. BUT now this alarm is going off all the time because message count is below 50. - bad

What is the best way to handle this kind of situation.

I found Alarms are the easiest route but I am open go with to the best practices and best solution.

In short I want to scale out when message count is 500 but when its below 50, go back to default configuration.

```
min = 2 
desired = 2
max  = 4
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you have described is a perfectly correct configuration.

You would configure two alarms:

- When `ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible` > 500, add 1 instance
- When `ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible` < 50, remove 1 instance

When the queue size is low, the number of instances will go down to the Minimum number of 2. The "< 50" alarm will still be in ALARM state, but the number of instances will not drop down below the Minimum, so there is no need to panic about the state of the alarm.

Comment: Thanks John. I just didn't like the alarm being 'Alarm' state and thought I was doing something wrong. Good to know others would do this way too ;)

Comment: Yeah. "ALARM" simple means "the condition is true". No need to be alarmed. :)