# Can I create an ASG with desired capacity of 1 and minimum group size of 0?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-auto-scaling

I want to create a job that will process a queue (SQS) every now and then (not scheduled). Is it possible for me to create an auto scaling group that starts with 1 instance (desired capacity), scaled out and then scaled down to zero once the queue is empty?

Is the desired capacity of 1, and minimum group size of zero a common pattern (solution) for this?

Comment: You mean like this? [How to Scale in and out based on SQS message level](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56455157/174777)

Comment: A little different. My goal is that all instances in the ASG will terminate when the queue is empty. In other words, how to start at one and end at 0.

Comment: You can certainly start at 1, and then the 'Scale-in' alarm will reduce it to zero if there are no messages. You could configure the alarms for `Scale-out if > 1` and `Scale-in if zero` and set the Auto-Scaling group to a Minimum of zero and a Maximum of 1.

Comment: Just be aware that `ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible` really is approximate -- it won't update as fast as the messages take to process. So, treat it as a slow scaling -- for example, only scale-in if after 15+ minutes of no messages. You might want to scale-out faster since you probably don't want messages waiting too long. Of course, these days it is much better to use an AWS Lambda function to process messages rather than EC2 instances. Any chance of converting your worker code to work as a Lambda function?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, though it's not clear to me why you would want to start your ASG at 1.

- If you get down to 0 instances, presumably you would need to scale out again at some future point in order to process new SQS messages. That means you need a scale-out alarm to take you from 0 to 1.
- If you start at 1 and have a scale-in alarm defined, presumably this would get triggered immediately if your SQS queue happens to be initially empty. So you would need the scale-out alarm to respond to the moment when your SQS queue begins receiving messages.

(I see that John Rotenstein covered some of the nuances of ASG scaling pretty well above. Agreed with him on that.)

Other options to consider:

1. Create a Lambda function to process your SQS messages. This is the easiest and all of your scaling concerns should be addressed implicitly. Your function will be invoked only when there is a message to process.
2. If you really need an EC2-based message processor, you could run that on [AWS Batch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/what-is-batch.html). Your AWS Batch [Compute Environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/compute_environments.html) would essentially perform the work of the ASG in your current architecture and spin up instances to run your message-processing code (which would need to be packaged as a Docker image) as-needed. You can connect SQS to AWS Batch using [Amazon EventBridge Pipes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-pipes.html) **or** by creating a small Lambda function to trigger the AWS Batch job (see [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69207784/starting-aws-batch-from-sqs-queue)).

Comment: My use case is for reprocessing the whole data (for building data warehouse), The items to reprocess get inserted to a queue, and the ASG will fetch from queue do some "heavy weight processing". Since it is a one time job (The queue only gets populated in case we need to re-process everything), the ASG should terminate once everything is done hence the minimum state of 0. So in my use use case, need to scale out when everything is finished.